# /trigger not working for datapacks in a specific Minecraft singleplayer world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I just tried installing some of the datapacks on VanillaTweaks for 1.14 (https://vanillatweaks.net/picker/datapacks/), and after following installment procedures, I was baffled to see that **I couldn't run any objectives via /trigger** (many of the tutorial/informative videos on each datapack on VanillaTweaks mentions and seems to imply that you need to run /trigger [the datapacks' objective] in order to get them to work.

To make this a bit easier, we can focus on two examples: the *More Mob Heads datapack*, which does not require any triggers and automatically seems to be working once installed, and the *Sethome datapack*, which you need to run /trigger sethome and /trigger home in order to both set your home and warp to that home. (there's no exact link to download these two specific datapacks, they are only downloadable by choosing them on the VanillaTweaks datapack picker and downloading)

When I load up the world, and run /datapack list, you can see that there are **3 datapacks currently recognized and enabled:** there are the two datapack examples (sethome and more mob heads), and the basic vanilla datapack which comes with all worlds.

[image]

You can also tell that the datapacks aren't just empty datapacks with nothing else, since when you type in /function you can see that the sethome datapack has data.

[image]

When killing a villager, you can see that the More Mob Heads datapack is working fine *(villagers have a 100% chance of dropping their head in this datapack, and they clearly don't drop them in default vanilla Minecraft, so the datapack **is** working.)*

[image]

But, with the functionality of this datapack essentially requiring /trigger (to set homes and to go to homes), and with /trigger showing no objectives whatsoever, it means that the datapack is basically unusable.

[image]

However, when testing on a separate completely vanilla world that I just created in the same exact version *(1.14.4)*, with the same exact datapacks, I noticed that **/trigger was working fine on this world.**

[image]

Also testing on a 1.14.4 vanilla test server running Spigot with just Essentials, the triggers were working fine, just like the newly-created vanilla world.

So my question is, **why isn't it working in my specific singleplayer world?** Note that the specific world being mentioned was converted from a vanilla 1.8 world to 1.14.4, so could this be the issue?

Should I try updating to 1.15, running some other command to activate these datapacks, or is there some other solution?

**World Download Link (the affected world only):** http://www.mediafire.com/file/vigrmgakzbwvjmt/Broken_datapack_world.zip/file

(I couldn't recover the old world due to a corrupted chunk, but I have a backup that is essentially an older version of that same world - likewise, /trigger for datapacks is not working on that world either. I think the reason the datapacks aren't entirely working is because of how I converted from 1.8 to 1.14, and I had to manually create the datapacks folder myself. I've also included the two datapacks mentioned throughout this question in the world, too. Note that the download is about 200-210 MB.)

Comment: This question is way too broad. You're essentially asking us to debug 28 entire datapacks at once, each of which could potentially be gigantic software projects. Please try to get a "[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" for your issue.

Comment: I guess that does make sense, I can probably single out only a single datapack to focus on.

Comment: I didn't read your entire edit, but if it's different in two different worlds, then you should upload the affected world.

Comment: Sorry for not being very active, I have been trying to deal with a corrupted chunk in the same world mentioned above. For now, I've put a download link (Mediafire) to a slightly older backup of that world.